# Why do triangulated points not project back to same image points in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, structure-from-motion, reprojection-error

I have two corresponding image points (2D) visualized by the same camera with intrinsic matrix K each coming from different camera poses (R1, t1, R2, t2). If I triangulate the corresponding image points to a 3D point and then reproject it back to the original cameras it only closely matches the original image point in the first camera. Can someone help me understand why? Here is a minimal example showing the issue:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up two cameras near each other

K = np.array([
    [718.856 ,   0.  ,   607.1928],
    [  0.  ,   718.856 , 185.2157],
    [  0.  ,     0.   ,    1.    ],
])

R1 = np.array([
    [1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1.]
])

R2 = np.array([
    [ 0.99999183 ,-0.00280829 ,-0.00290702],
    [ 0.0028008  , 0.99999276, -0.00257697],
    [ 0.00291424 , 0.00256881 , 0.99999245]
])

t1 = np.array([[0.], [0.], [0.]])

t2 = np.array([[-0.02182627], [ 0.00733316], [ 0.99973488]])

P1 = np.hstack([R1.T, -R1.T.dot(t1)])
P2 = np.hstack([R2.T, -R2.T.dot(t2)])

P1 = K.dot(P1)
P2 = K.dot(P2)

# Corresponding image points
imagePoint1 = np.array([371.91915894, 221.53485107])
imagePoint2 = np.array([368.26071167, 224.86262512])

# Triangulate
point3D = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, imagePoint1, imagePoint2).T
point3D = point3D[:, :3] / point3D[:, 3:4]
print(point3D)

# Reproject back into the two cameras
rvec1, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R1)
rvec2, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R2)

p1, _ = cv2.projectPoints(point3D, rvec1, t1, K, distCoeffs=None)
p2, _ = cv2.projectPoints(point3D, rvec2, t2, K, distCoeffs=None)

# measure difference between original image point and reporjected image point 

reprojection_error1 = np.linalg.norm(imagePoint1 - p1[0, :])
reprojection_error2 = np.linalg.norm(imagePoint2 - p2[0, :])

print(reprojection_error1, reprojection_error2)
```

The reprojection error in the first camera is always good (< 1px) but the second one is always large.

Comment: Do your rotation and translation matrices make sense ? Seems like the cameras are near perfectly aligned and separated by almost 1 unit exactly... Probably unlikely which leads me to question your calibration

Comment: The second pose was computed using `recoverPose` which is why it is exactly 1 unit magnitude in a mostly forward direction. @kevinkayaks

Comment: I think so. The `R2` and `t2` are computed with `_, R, t, mask = cv2.recoverPose(E, ...)`. And then `P = K [ R' | -R'*t ]` right? @rayryeng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember how you're constructing the projection matrix with the transpose of the rotation matrix combined with the negative of the translation vector.  You must do the same thing when you're putting this into `cv2.projectPoints`.

Therefore, take the transpose of the rotation matrix and put it into `cv2.Rodrigues`.  Finally, supply the negative of the translation vector into `cv2.projectPoints`:

```
# Reproject back into the two cameras
rvec1, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R1.T) # Change
rvec2, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(R2.T) # Change

p1, _ = cv2.projectPoints(point3D, rvec1, -t1, K, distCoeffs=None) # Change
p2, _ = cv2.projectPoints(point3D, rvec2, -t2, K, distCoeffs=None) # Change
```

Doing this we now get:

```
[[-12.19064      1.8813655   37.24711708]]
0.009565768222768252 0.08597237597736622
```

To be absolutely sure, here are the relevant variables:

```
In [32]: p1
Out[32]: array([[[371.91782052, 221.5253794 ]]])

In [33]: p2
Out[33]: array([[[368.3204979 , 224.92440583]]])

In [34]: imagePoint1
Out[34]: array([371.91915894, 221.53485107])

In [35]: imagePoint2
Out[35]: array([368.26071167, 224.86262512])
```

We can see that the first few significant digits match and we expect that there is a slight loss in precision due to this being a least-squares solve to where the points triangulate to.

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng appreciate the help. The re-projection errors now looks healthy. Have I been confusing my understandings of the "projection matrix" vs. the "pose" of the camera perhaps.

Comment: @nickponline Yes and it's very normal.  Pose is simply the extrinsics, so rotation and translation.  Projection matrix is both the extrinsics and intrinisics, so the only difference from Pose and Projection matrix is the additional multiplication of the intrinsics (i.e. `K`).  Remember that the Projection matrix maps points from 3D to 2D.  A pose is simply a movement of the camera without mapping what is seen in that field of view onto the image plane.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking for a concrete example on how to use the triangulation function of cv2 have a look at this post on GitHub

```bash
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Test
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print('Triangulate 3d points - units in meters')
# triangulatePoints requires 2xn arrays, so transpose the points
p = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, x1.T, x2.T)
# however, homgeneous point is returned
p /= p[3]
print('Projected point from openCV:',  p.T)

p = triangulate_nviews([P1, P2], [x1h, x2h])
print('Projected point from 2 camera views:',  p)

p = triangulate_nviews([P1, P2, P3], [x1h, x2h, x3h])
print('Projected point from 3 camera views:',  p)

# cv2 two image points - not homgeneous on input
p = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, x1h2[:, :2].T, x2h2[:, :2].T)
p /= p[3]
print('Projected points from openCV:\n', p.T)

p = triangulate_points(P1, P2, x1h2, x2h2)
print('Projected point from code:\n',  p)
```

[code in gist](https://gist.github.com/davegreenwood/e1d2227d08e24cc4e353d95d0c18c914)

Comment: Welcome to SO Merwanski. For [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121), please do not post images of code. If you just copy that code from your link, it will make for a better answer. Thanks